# How to transform an XML file using XSLT

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt

I am new to coding and need help with parsing an XML file using XSLT and providing output in HTML.
I have the code below.
I need the script name and type which has result="INFORMATION"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="class.xsl"?>
<TestLog>
 <Event dpIter="0">
  <Event Timestamp="27-Dec-2012 04:16:26.830 PM" Type="Script Start" Headline="Script       start [DSE.DSEBalanceInquiry_FC.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003]" Result="INFORMATION">
    <Property line_number="1"/>
    <Property script_iter_count="0"/>
    <Property script_name="DSE.DSEBalanceInquiry_FC.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003"/>
    <Property script_id="DSE.DSEBalanceInquiry_FC.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003.java"/>
  </Event>
  <Event Timestamp="27-Dec-2012 04:16:26.830 PM" Type="General" Headline="D:\TestAutomation\LogLevels.txt (The system cannot find the file specified.)" Result="INFORMATION">
    <Property script_name="DSE.DSEBalanceInquiry_FC.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003"/>
    <Property line_number="35"/>
    <Property script_id="DSE.DSEBalanceInquiry_FC.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003.java"/>
  </Event>
 </Event>
</TestLog>
```

XSLT code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">; 
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <html> 
  <body> 
  <h2></h2> 
  <table border="1">
  <tr> 
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>Result</th> 
 </tr> 
 <xsl:for-each select="TestLog/Event"> 
 <tr> 
  <td><xsl:value-of select="Type"/></td> 
  <td><xsl:value-of select="Result"/></td> 
 </tr> 
 </xsl:for-each> 
   </table> 
  </body> 
  </html> 
  </xsl:template> 
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please add your XSLT stylesheet (what you have tried so far) to the post.

Comment: I tried to get the type from event , but didnt got any output
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="Event/Type"> 
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Did you even look at the most basic example of how XSLT works?

Comment: yes i was i tried to get the event or type from the xml but i was unable to get it.
<xsl:value-of select="/'Event Timestamp'[@Type='Script End']"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to access `Event` nodes if their `Result` attribute equals "INFORMATION".

**NOTE**: This informs you about the general principles of XSLT, since your question is broad and unspecific. More precise answers can be given only if the question is more precise.

In XSLT, you specify such restrictions in square brackets:

```
<xsl:template match="Event[parent::Event and @Result='INFORMATION']">
```

The above line of code matches `Event` elements if they are a child of a superior `Event` element and if their @Result is right.

Here is a full stylesheet as an example for finding specific nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TestLog|Event[parent::Testlog]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Event[parent::Event and @Result='INFORMATION']">
  <xsl:text>Type: </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@Type"/>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>Script name: </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="Property/@script_name"/>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Property"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If applied to your input XML, this is the result:

```
Type: Script Start
Script name: DSE.DSEBalanceInquiry_FC.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003
Type: General
Script name: DSE.DSEBalanceInquiry_FC.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003
```

It finds the wanted `Event` nodes and outputs their `Type` attribute, together with the `script_name` attribute of one of their child elements.

---

**EDIT** (responding to your comment):

The following stylesheet does what you want, I have modified several things:

- the namespace for XSL *must* be "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
- you are matching "/" (the document node). Therefore, you have to navigate through the tree to find the nodes for the `for-each` like this: `TestLog/Event/Event`
- your code contains a semicolon ";" that should be removed
- attributes must be prefixed with "@" (or attribute::, for that matter)

All of them together lead me to believe that you have never tried to run this yourself.

Full stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
  <body>
     <h2></h2>
     <table border="1">
        <tr>
           <th>Type</th>
           <th>Result</th>
        </tr>
           <xsl:for-each select="TestLog/Event/Event[@Result='INFORMATION']">
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Type"/>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Result"/>
                 </td>
              </tr>
           </xsl:for-each>
     </table>
   </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i have written this code but i am not getting any values , im getting only hedders. did i miss anything?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/"><html>
  <body>
  <h2></h2>
  <table border="1">

<tr>
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>Result</th>
<tr>

<xsl:for-each select="TestLog/Event">

<tr>  
   <td><xsl:value-of select="Type"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="Result"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Please _edit_ your post instead of posting this as a comment.

Comment: Thankyou Mathias Muller for your information. My apologies for not providing you proper data. I am new to the coding , bit confused on what details i have to place it

Comment: You're welcome. The StackOverflow of saying "thank you" is by accepting the answer if it was helpful (mark the tick on the left).

Comment: One question,could you suggest a tool which gives me the output when i provide xml and xslt inputs ?

Comment: Such a tool is called an _XSLT processor_ and you have two options. **1**: It is fairly certain that an XSLT processor is implemented in your browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox...). To make it work, you have to reference the stylesheet in your XML file (google it). **2**: Or use a tool that is independent of a browser and that is e.g. run from the command line. A prominent one is _Saxon_.

Comment: Thanyou for your response. i am using w3schools tool